# c# combobox autocomplete set display text and value

Tags: c#, combobox, autocomplete

I need to create a combobox autocomplete which display `text` `Name` but when I click on `text` it gets `value` "`ID`" binding with "Name". I have already created a code but it is not working and I'm so confusing with `set display text` and `value` into combobox and autocomplete `data-source` binding.

```
private void loadAutoCompleteValues()
{
    autoCompleteCombo.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
    autoCompleteCombo.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;

    DataTable products;
    con.MysqlQuery("select * from products");
    products = con.QueryEx();
    Dictionary<string, string> comboSource = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < products.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = products.Rows[i];
        comboSource.Add(dr["id"].ToString(), dr["name"].ToString());
    }

    autoCompleteCombo.DataSource = new BindingSource(comboSource, null);
    autoCompleteCombo.DisplayMember = "Value";
    autoCompleteCombo.ValueMember = "Key";
}

private void autoCompleteCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string key = ((KeyValuePair<string, string>)autoCompleteCombo.SelectedItem).Key;
    string value = ((KeyValuePair<string, string>)autoCompleteCombo.SelectedItem).Value;

    MessageBox.Show(key + "   " + value);
}
```

Comment: What you meant by Not working? is that message box is showing?

Comment: No, combo box is empty!

Comment: It is working !! I forgot `db con = new db();`  but `auto complete` not working ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be incorrect here, however using your code I simply added the line `autoCompleateCombo.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;` to your code and it worked as expected.

```
  autoCompleateCombo.DataSource = new BindingSource(comboSource, null);
  autoCompleateCombo.DisplayMember = "Value";
  autoCompleateCombo.ValueMember = "Key";
  autoCompleateCombo.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems; //<-- Added this line
```